# Selenium and BeautifulSoup can't fetch all HTML content

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping the bottom table labeled "Capacity : Operationally Available - Evening" on https://lngconnection.cheniere.com/#/ccpl

I am able to get all the HTML and everything shows up when I prettify() print the HTML but the parsers can't find it when I give a command to find the specific information I need.

Here's my script:

```
cc_driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/.../Desktop/chromedriver')
cc_driver.get('https://lngconnection.cheniere.com/#/ccpl')
cc_html = cc_driver.page_source

cc_content = soup(cc_html, 'html.parser')
cc_driver.close()
cc_table = cc_content.find('table', class_='k-selectable')
#print(cc_content.prettify())
print(cc_table.prettify())
```

now when I do the

```
print(cc_table.prettify())
```

The output is everything except the actual table data. Is there some error in my code or in their HTML that is hiding the actual table values? I'm able to see it when I print everything Selenium captures on the page. The HTML also doesn't have specific ID tags for any of the cell values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking into the HTML which is not yet complete. All the elements have not yet returned from the javascript. So you can do a webdriver wait.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

cc_driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"path for driver")
cc_driver.get('https://lngconnection.cheniere.com/#/ccpl')
WebDriverWait(cc_driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 
'#capacityGrid > table > tbody')))
cc_html = cc_driver.page_source

cc_content = soup(cc_html, 'html.parser')
cc_driver.close()
cc_table = cc_content.find('table', class_='k-selectable')
#print(cc_content.prettify())
print(cc_table.prettify())
```

This will wait for the element to be present.

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked, I did not know about adding waits. I had to find by XPATH instead of CSS_SELECTOR but it is one and the same, thank you Mohammed brother

Answer (score 0):

This should help you getting table html

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

cc_driver = webdriver.Chrome('../chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
cc_driver.get('https://lngconnection.cheniere.com/#/ccpl')
cc_html = cc_driver.page_source

cc_content = bs(cc_html, 'html.parser')
cc_driver.close()
cc_table = cc_content.find('table', attrs={'class':'k-selectable'})

#print(cc_content.prettify())
print(cc_table.prettify())
```